# Improper assignment with rectangular empty matrix error

Tags: matlab

I have the following code (see below) which I hope is self-explanatory. When I run the code using VEC A1/B1 or VEC A2/B2 commenting out the relevant bits, the code works without issues. But when I use the arrays A and B which is what I actually intend to do, matlab gives me the following error:

Improper assignment with rectangular empty matrix.

It says that the error is in this line of code:

```
 prePr(j,:)=a(a>B(j) & a<B((j+1)))
```

this suggests that it loops correctly for the condition when i=1 but gets stuck when i=2 which is something I am failing to understand. Would be a great help if someone can offer suggestion. Thank you.

```
RatePu=31.25;
RatePr=250;

ratioRate=RatePr/RatePu;

A=[1:3,5:11,13:19;2:8,10:16,18:20;];     
B=[4,12,20;1,9,17;];


% A=[1:3,5:11,13:19;];   % VEC A1
% A=[2:8,10:16,18:20;];  % VEC A2

% B=[4,12,20;];   % VEC B1
% B=[1,9,17;];   % VEC B2


  NumTP=size(A,1);


 prePr=zeros(length(B),ratioRate-1);

 for i=1:NumTP

     a=A(i,:);
     b=B(i,:);


  if b(1)==1
    for j=1:length(b)-1


   prePr(j,:)=a(a>B(j) & a<B((j+1)))

    end




   elseif b(1)>1

    for j=1:length(b)


  if j==1

        prePr(j,1:max(a(a<(b(1)))))=a(a<b(j)) ;

   else

         prePr(j,:)= a(a>b(j-1) & a<b((j-1)+1))
  end

    end

  end

 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because for i=2 you have that prePr is an empty matrix.

I would suggest this:

```
x==a(a>B(j) & a<B((j+1)));
 if numel(x)==0
  prePr(j,:)=NaN;
 else
  prePr(j,:)=x;
 end
```